# Split Excel workbook into spreadsheets based on 2 empty rows

Tags: excel, vba

I often import huge raports from SAP including lots of customers information, often more than 15-20k rows. Generated raport includes 3 small raports separated by 2 empty rows. I was looking for some solution to automatically split that huge raport into 3 smaller ones into 3 seperate spreadsheets based either on row value (every raport starts with PersNr header and ends with ** Summ) or empty row count value equal to 2, but I can't find it. Maybe some VBA solution, any kind of help will be helpful.

Here's an example of how it looks like with first column:

```
PersNr

3000113
3000113
3000113
* 3000113
3005040
3005040
3005040
* 3005040

** Summ


PersNr

4002119
4002119
4002119
* 4002119
4008029
4008029
4008029
* 4008029

** Summ


PersNr

798412123
798412123
798412123
* 798412123
687428901
687428901
687428901
* 687428901

** Summ
```

Note that in this case normal breaking with 1 empty row doesn't work as I have some single empty rows, I need to split when there are 2 empty rows.

Searched google for over 1 hour with no perfect solution, most solutions were column based, not row based or fit for 1 empty row and I couldn't adapt if for my purpose.

Comment: If data starts with `PersNr` and ends with `** Summ`: Why look for empty rows?

Comment: Sometimes based on user's windows region settings raport can generate with different ending and we sometimes share raports. It would work only for mine raports, but anyway volume of such raports is huge and some vba code is faster than manually editing big files. I found some codes for splitting with 1 empty row, but it was returning errors and it doesn't fit mine case, I need split when 2 empty rows.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the following code. It has two nested loops, the outer loop runs over all data, the inner loop searches for 2 consecutive empty rows. When those empty rows are found, a new sheet is created and the data from `startRow` to the found row is copied and `startRow` is set to the start of the next block. This repeats until all data is processed.

The code reads the relevant data into memory to speed up the process, but the logic stays the same. I also added a small function to check if the complete row is empty.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitReport(Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing)
    Const ColCount = 5          ' Define number of rows to check/copy
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ws.Parent
    
    Dim row As Long, startRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
    ' Read into memory to speed up data (+2 to ensure that we have 2 empty lines at the end.
    Dim data
    data = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow + 2, ColCount).Value
    
    startRow = 1
    Do While startRow < lastRow
        row = startRow
        ' Search for 2 empty rows
        Do While Not isEmptyRow(data, row) Or Not isEmptyRow(data, row + 1)
            DoEvents
            row = row + 1
        Loop
        
        ' Copy data to new sheet
        wb.Worksheets.Add after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, 1), ws.Cells(row, ColCount)).Copy wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
        
        ' Start next Block of data
        startRow = row + 2
    Loop
End Sub


Private Function isEmptyRow(data, row As Long) As Boolean
    Dim col As Long
    For col = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        If Not IsEmpty(data(row, col)) Then Exit Function
    Next
    isEmptyRow = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  but for some reason I cannot run the macro with (Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing). Like the macro doesn't run and I can't see it listed when Alt+F8. I am using 365 version if it collides somehow.

Comment: You need to tell the Sub on which sheet is should run. If you always want to run it while the sheet with the data is selected, you can remove the parameter and instead declare `ws` as Worksheetand assign `ActiveSheet`, or use `ActiveSheet` instead of `ws`, or use a `With` statement.